# Can't connect ssh to openshift servers from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openshift

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to connect to the openshift servers and failing spectacularly.

I have tried a few things :

- Deleted and recreated my ssh public keys
- tried to connect using both domain name and IP address.

When I use ssh - I get

> Connection closed by 52.91.54.141

When i try to use git to push my code :

> Connection closed by 52.91.54.141
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I am the only one with access to the repository, and if I don't have rights I don't know who does.

Update - 3rd Jan 09:45

This is the what I get with `ssh -vvv`

```
tony@laptop .../SuffolkCycle:$ ssh -vvv 5688275389f5cf4404000147@suffolkcycleride-emfsolutions.rhcloud.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to suffolkcycleride-emfsolutions.rhcloud.com [52.91.54.141] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "suffolkcycleride-emfsolutions.rhcloud.com" from file "/home/tony/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/tony/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
Connection closed by 52.91.54.141
```

Weirdly with this setup I have connected successfully once (which to me suggests a far end issue causing all of the other failures). There is no reported issues on the openshift servers though.

Comment: It seems like something is not quite right with your ssh config. Try ssh -vvv for more verbose debug output and also double check permissions and file ownership of your keys in your ~/.ssh directory - your private keys should have no more than 0600 (-rw-------)

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of `ssh -vvv` - I don't really understand what it is telling me.

Comment: Would love to understand why this has already got a close vote - sad that no-one else has attempted to help (other than jdt), but are already convinved this is a duplicate.

Comment: This part looks important: debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key  Have you verified that your keys were created correctly?  Did you create rsa keys or dsa keys?  Did you re-run rhc setup to upload your new keys?

Comment: I used `rhc setup` to recreate and upload the new keys. From what I understand though - `id_rsa` is the private key - and `id_rsa.pub` is the public key - it is certainly the content of `id_rsa.pub` which is uploaded to the openshift servers.

Comment: FYI: The debug3 message about RSA1 keys can be safely ignored, its just a terrible way of saying that your key is not a version 1 key. It will be a v2 key.

Comment: I just tried to ssh to the host and made it a little further along than shown in your example, the problem seems to start at "debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent" .. My system's next log entry is: "got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY" whereas your log shows 'expecting ... ' .. I am not sure what would cause this yet though.

Comment: @jdt I was wondering if that `expecting` message was a time out ?

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I am not sure, it does look that way.